# Get index of currently focused input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the index of the current input text field I'm currently in? I'm trying to jump to the next input field after pressing enter. This is what I've got:

```
 var index = $('input:text').index(this); 
 $('input:text')[nextIndex].focus();
```

But it's not going to the next one..

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work fine:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var index = $("input[type='text']").index(this);
        $("input[type='text']").eq(index + 1).focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uJsMQ/